# How would we perceive light arriving to us from a distance source?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light

Imagine being in space 5 light minutes from the source of a beam of light.  The source of the beam of light is initially switched off.

The light is turned on.  When it is turned on you would see nothing until it arrived.  As it arrived, the phase front would be curved and so I would expect that as the light arrived it would be faint and grow in brightness.

Would that be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are assuming a thermal light source. In such a source, excited electrons emit photons chaotically after the light source is switched on. It does not matter whether the light source is 5 light minutes away from you or one metre away, what arrives is a stream of unpolarised photons in a broad frequency band.

Of course, the number of emitted photons increases during the switch-on process, so there is a transition process from a small number of photons from the original temperature of the source to a noticeable number of photons of higher frequencies. However, you will not perceive the periodicity of the beam, it simply does not exist.

It is different with a radio source. Take an antenna rod and periodically accelerate the electrons on its surface. These now emit polarised photons with changing intensity and sign. Depending on the setting of the wave generator, you can perceive/measure the change in intensity of the radio wave in the target.

Now there is the special case of the "lighthouse". A rotating source that ejects high-energy particles along magnetic poles. Photons are also emitted in the process. If the photon beam periodically crosses your position, you will also perceive/measure a periodicity of the number of incoming photons. However, this will not be a sinusoidal wave, but rather a square wave (staircase-shaped).

Comment: Thanks for that excellent response.   The essence of my original question was what would be the visual experience of seeing a torch or thermal light source turned on in complete darkness - some distance away - I think you answered that .

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be asking about [*dispersion*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(optics)). If so, light is not dispersed by empty space. If the light was instantly switched on,  then that is how you would see it, despite your being five light minutes away from the source.

Comment: Thanks  - I think I should have thought about this before posting.  Yes, at the photon level it would be a plane wave.